# Ubuntu for my Asus netbook

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I have an asus netbook with the following specs:

```
      Processor: AMD C-50 Processor (2 CPUs), ~1.0GHz
         Memory: 1024MB RAM
```

Available OS Memory: 750MB RAM
       Also have AMD HD 6250 as graphic card.

I want to know what is the best ubuntu version for this hardware? i have tried ubuntu 12.04 and 11.10 and they both were sluggish. I had them installed as Wubi..Is it my machine that is just slow or its the wubi installation?(full install vs wubi install) but then again I heard ubuntu does not require high spec hardware..please help, windows starter is just painfully slow

Comment: I was runnning 12.04 on a similar Netbook. If you haven't installed the AMD binary graphics drivers yet, do so, they make a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have a much more underpowered machine than yours (512Mb RAM, 700MHz processor) and it runs Bodhi Linux (Ubuntu with the Enlightenment desktop) fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say how much wubi affects the speed - but your machine is that slow. Try Lubuntu, this one should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Installing by Wubi simply launches the installer from Windows.

The version of Ubuntu you use is not as critical as what you put on it.Ubuntu relies on 3D graphics to draw the interface, which slows small systems down. There are many options for you if you are set on using Ubuntu.

The most noticeable resource hog on a netbook is the Unity shell (Compiz); if you want Ubuntu to run faster, I suggest using another desktop environment.

You have many options, like [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org), [OpenBox](http://www.openbox.org), and [LXDE](http://www.lxde.org) to name a few. Each of these has its perks and drawbacks, but the overarching theme is minimalism and resource-sparing performance. You won't have as many of the graphical luxuries as Unity offers, but your system will certainly run more quickly.

If you use a new desktop environment and decide that you need a Dash-like search and command center, you might try [Gnome-do](http://do.cooperteam.net) or [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) , which has much of the same functionality with far less overhead.